# I need a lightweight CLI Linux Distro that can support Python

Tags: linux, python-3, terminal

I have a spare raspberry pi, I figured i'd use it for a python releated task, is there a cut down Linux Distro that does not include a GUI but only a CLI that can also fully support running python programs, install modules through pip, so on and so forth. It's one of the early raspberry pi's so it isn't very powerful, so I thought having a lightweight operating system may help

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspbian Stretch Lite is a CLI only Linux distro.

https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite_latest

Comment: Note that the lite image comes with Python 2 only. Install Python 3 with `sudo apt install python3` and you probably want pip too: `sudo apt install python3-pip`

Comment: @ben_nuttall It is not right that python3 is not available on a default **Raspbian Stretch Lite** installation. On my RasPi with Stretch Lite with `python3 --version` I get `Python 3.5.3`. I do not need to install it.